# set onMarkerClickListener along with title, but either one of them shows up. How to show both?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm using this line to generate a title for the marker-

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Last location"));
```

Then if I set onMarkerClickListener

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Clicked on marker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
```

Marker title wouldn't show. I need to show both, toast and marker title; how to do that, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line `marker.showInfoWindow();` inside the onMarkerClick method.